# How can I get the command-line arguments in an embedded Pig script?

Tags: python, arguments, apache-pig

I'm writing an embedded pig script in python, and I'd like to pass arguments like this:

```
$ pig myscript.py arg1 arg2
```

I'd expect `sys.argv` to be `['myscript.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']`, but it's empty.

Any idea how I can pass command-line arguments to an embedded pig script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.argv` should include the name of the executable, so it'd probably be `['myscript.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']`, but it looks like this was an open issue that was fixed in a recent version of Pig: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2548.

Perhaps check that you're using something newer than 0.10.0.

Answer (score 1):

Reopening this thread...  Basically, I've created an environmental variable that I use in my script:

```
$ export file_in=filename; pig -useHCatalog ./POC_Python_Wrapper.py
```

and in the script:

```
import os
file_in = os.getenv('file_in', 'Unknown')
```